# Can a broken ethernet cable give link but no ip?

Tags: ip, ethernet, dhcp, cable, cabling

I'm just wondering what the structure is here. Can an ethernet cable give link and seemingly work fine, but cause problems with DHCP traffic between two nodes? One part of me is thinking that link means that traffic is coming through OK, but at the same time you can have link but a massive amount of dropped packages if the cable is physically damaged, right?

So then the follow-up to this is, could you say that ip problems are very *unlikely* to be caused by a broken ethernet cable, and if it is, it should almost certainly be visibly damaged?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in general a broken cable can cause a lot of different trouble, have you replaced the cable for testing? I've seen situations where the link was detected (e.g. green LED on) but the ethernet did not work.

Comment: @AlexanderTruemper I suggest you make that the answer.

Comment: 2nd that is the answer, I've had all kind of problems ranging from slow response / low bandwith to failing to even connect all due to bad cabling. Most of the time the underlying cause is a high percentage of packet loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in general a broken cable can cause a lot of different trouble, have you replaced the cable for testing? I've seen situations where the link was detected (e.g. green LED on) but the ethernet did not work. –